# Extract html source code into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, web-scraping, getelementbyid

I am trying to simply paste the content or innertext into excel using getElementByID function.
The content is actually the iframe link which I am trying to extract it and paste into cell.
The photo shown is the html source code.

```
 Sub GetData()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim result As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5925865"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop


    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) ' For internal page refresh or loading

    Set htmldoc = ie.document
    Set Results = HTML.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = Results.innerText

End Sub
```

[html source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LylPS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use consistent variable naming in your code. If you put Option Explicit at the top of your code that will help.

You want to access the `src` attribute of the `iframe` to get the URL shown.

If you plan to use the new URL then you actually want the part before the "#". This means changing to:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Split(ie.document.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe").src, "#")(0)
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5925865"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") = ie.document.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe").src
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: No wonder I could solve it out. Thank once again for your solution QHarr.